# How to scan for BLE devices in flutter background

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

I am using `flutter_blue` plugin to scan for BLE device i have a pressure monitoring device which  broadcasts BLE signal when there is a change in pressure. i want to receive these values in my flutter app then send them to Firestore.

Everything works fine when the app is in foreground but it does not works when app is in background.

Below is my scanner function

```
  void scanner() {
   flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(days: 5));
   flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    if (results != null && results.length > 0) {
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
       bool checkpoint1 = results[i].device.id.toString() == frontDevice;
       bool checkpoint2 = results[i].device.id.toString() == rearDevice;

       if (checkpoint1) {
        first = results[i].advertisementData.manufacturerData;
       }

      if (checkpoint2) {
        second = results[i].advertisementData.manufacturerData;
      }

      if (results.length - 1 == i) {

        if (first != null && second != null) {
          deviceData(first, second);
        }

      }

    }
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: You'll probably have to use [isolates](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) for this. See [these](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) docs for more info on background execution.

Answer (score 2):

If you start a background service, then please do it cross platform, unless you need this service to run while the app is running (not as a background fetch, meaning the app is in the foreground, but is running not on the main thread).

Please use this package here if you need to run the **flutter_blue** plugin. If you try to run any other plugins, it will fail:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate

Also if you need this to run as a background fetch, then please use this plugin here:
https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run something on background mode[when app is minimized] then you have to drill down to platform specific solutions. At-least for iOS Isolate or any other solution will not work because `iOS pauses app` after few seconds when user minimized app.

For iOS that you need to enable `BackgroundMode` to make iOS aware that you are using specific services and you need a privision to running app on background. Only few things can be run on background and Bluetooth is one of the thing. You need to setup few things in iOS project. Here you will find details: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW7

For Android you may use Foreground Services to keep running your Bluetooth related stuff.[Note that I have very basic knowledge about Android. There could be better suggestion]

For Android, there are some limitations like if you try to write Characteristics from thread except Main Thread then you may get exception. Here are few important notes about it: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le
Refer to "`Caution! Important remarks / API limitations`" section specially.

**Note for iOS:** As far as I understand Isolate can run code snippet on background thread but can not run something when app is minimzed and iOS is pausing execution of source code.

Comment: Even Specifying `UIBackgroundModes` in  `info.plist` won't work in iOS ?